# Проверка на два события одновременно

Tags: javascript, события

Как сделать проверку на два события одновременно на чистом JS?
По принципу: если есть `mouseout` и `mouseup`, то выполнить условие.

Comment: Каким образом эти два события могут произойти на одном элементе одновременно?

Comment: @Visman единственный пришедший мне в голову вариант, который ближе всего подходит к "одновременно" (но, конечно, им не является) - это что-то [вроде такого](http://jsfiddle.net/b3xzho2e/). Не удивлюсь, если автору просто нужно, чтобы произошло и то событие, и другое. Возможно, с ограниченным промежутком времени между ними.

Comment: Неправильно понял сначала ваш вопрос. События обрабатываются всегда последовательно. В вашем случае необходимо найти совпадение двух состояний. Чтобы этого добиться нужно при наступлении событий фиксировать в виде некоторых флагов эти два состояния и сбрасывать при наступлении событий, которые эти состояния отменяют.

Comment: Еще просто любопытно: Drag&Drop в пределах одного контейнера пытаетесь реализовать?

Comment: Resizable елемент. При изменении размера, если увести мышь за пределы елемента и отпустить кнопку мыши, движение елемента не прекращается, а продолжает движение мыши. Исходя из этого и возникла проблема с реализацией.

Comment: @tutankhamun именно его)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я делал примерно так:

```js
var mouse_out_state = false;
var mouse_up_state = false;
//слушаем
document.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    mouse_out_state = !mouse_out_state;
    compare();
    mouse_out_state = false;
    mouse_up_state = false;
});
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    mouse_up_state = !mouse_up_state;
    compare();
});
//скидываем значения
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    mouse_up_state = false;
});
document.addEventListener("onmouseover", function(e) {
    mouse_out_state = false;;
});
//проверяем
function compare() {
    if (mouse_out_state && mouse_up_state) {
        alert('AAA works?');
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот только почему `mouse_out_state = !mouse_out_state` а не `mouse_out_state = true` ?

Comment: mouse_out_state = true и mouse_out_state = !false это одно и тоже

Comment: Результат да, но вычислений при присваиваниии констант меньше. Вот и стало интересно, зачем?

Comment: @tutankhamun если чесно не задумывался над этим, накатал по быстрому. Но если вдаватся в производительность то лучше 'true' прописать, и меньше шансов что баги вылезут

Comment: Вот как-то это все странно работает. Просто вожу курсор мыши после нажатия кнопки туда-сюда и на всякий выход с элемента вылазит алерт. Разве так должно работать-то?

Comment: @Visman Все зависит от задачи у топикстартера. С учетом его последнего комментария, флаг нужен один и его нужно сбрасывать по `mousedown` и `mouseover` и накапливать по `mouseout` и `mouseup`. Если флаг > 1, то выполнять действие

Comment: @tutankhamun, так не должен 100500 раз срабатывать алерт. Отпустил кнопку мыши на элементе, один раз ушел с элемента -> один алерт. Сейчас код в этом ответе работает неправильно.

Comment: Задача у меня сделать нормально работающий resize елемента. При уведении мыши с зажатой кнопкой дейстие изменения размера должно продолжаться, но при отпускании кнопки - прекращаться. На данный момент - при `mouseup` изменение размера тянется за мышью.

Comment: Разобрался, ребята. Туплю я.

Comment: @Baga Мне вот интересно, `mouseout` вообще понадобился? :)

Comment: @Visman прав, подправил. но вобытия это такая ж... что нужно под конкретный случай переделывать

Comment: @Baga, то есть вопрос можно ставить на закрытие? Или этот ответ будет отмечен вами как правильный?

Comment: @Visman Зачем его закрывать. Идея в ответе правильная. Текущей формулировке вопроса соответствует. Зачем человеку репутацию снижать.

Comment: @Baga Я бы, на вашем месте, отметил данный вопрос как правильный

Comment: @tutankhamun Нет, `mouseuot` не понадобился. Решил добавлением события `mouseup` на `document`

Comment: Да, идея верная, отметил верным.